# Php while loop with js variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**The plan:**

Basically I have a set of clothing items stored in a table each containing "item_name" "item_id" and "item_shortcode" I want to have a link per clothing item, when the user clicks the link the item needs to be added to an array (the selected array)

---

I'm trying to create a javascript object based off the data I've gathered from the mySQL database, then pass that data to a function when a div is clicked to my method.

this is an example:

```
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ 
?>

<script>
    var item = new Object();
    item.itemName = <?php echo json_encode($row['item_name']); ?>;
</script>

<?php
            echo "<div id=\"".$row['item_name']."\" class=\"choice\" onclick=\"SetSelectedChoice(item);\">";
            //echo $row['item_name'];
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

EDIT: this is just an example I'll be populating my object with lots of data, not just item_name

problem is the last object seems to be assigned to every div in while loop.

Anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: alright, put your name in quotes or you may end up with item.itemName = Some long string that will cause a horrible error;

Comment: Also, in case nobody will yell at you for this - you should switch to PDO or mysqli. mysql_ functions are deprecated and will soon be wiped out completely.

Comment: gah had no idea that mysql function have need superseded!

Comment: I would just turn the php collection into an array and jsonencode it directly to a js variable. or better yet, fetch it with ajax at that point.

Comment: @Kevin B That sounds like a better solution cheers

Comment: For anyone interested great tutorial... although I looked up mysqli and created my php written in that mysql extension http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining item on every iteration. Why not do something like this:

As per edit, you can create an item array and populate it in the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var objects = new Array();
</script>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var item = new Object();
        item.itemName = '<?php echo json_encode($row['item_name']); ?>';
        objects.push(item);
    </script>
    <div id="<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" class="choice">
            <?php echo $row['item_name']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

then in js OUTSIDE of your loop:

```
$('.choice').on('click', function(){
    SetSelectedChoice($(this).html());
});

function SetSelectedChoice(name)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++)
    {
        if(objects[i].itemName == name)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I wouldn't really recommend this kind of weird loop for comparing names. I just don't know what else you are doing with passing the name to this function. I would pass the item id or the index value and directly access an item in the array instead of a loop. Make sense?

Basically, stop using onclick. The whole world is leaning more on listeners. Secondly, no need to create an object at all. You don't seem to be using it and even if you did, you didn't put single quotes around the name like you should for strings. Thirdly, please break out of php to write html. It's just cleaner and easier. Morely, assign the item's id to the id parameter. It gets really ugly to have names and spaces in the ids of elements. And you don't really seem to need one since you don't use it in your example. None the less, I put it in there in case you wanted to access it like `$(this).attr('id')` in the on click listener.

But if I missed the point, perhaps you can clarify and I may update to better fit your needs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please check the edit, I've got about 5 fields I'll be populating that object with.

Comment: updated to more closely match your needs, though this should still be cleaned up a little.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i honestly don't know if i really got you, but if i see it right, then you simply overwrite the item-object in every run of the while-loop.
After the last loop (after this comes the output) the variable "item" is set to the last result of the loop, so clicking on any div will return "item" - the last item of the loop.

As a solution, try to save the rows name in the div as a parameter, like

```
echo "<div id=\"".$row['item_name']."\" class=\"choice\" onclick=\"SetSelectedChoice(\'".$row['item_name']."\');\">";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please check the edit, I've got about 5 fields I'll be populating that object with.

Comment: I don't know how this changes the cause of the problem by overwriting or the solution by handling the item in the parameters (like in my example) or over an attached function retrieving the informations, like in Kai's example.